# Get URL parameters condition

Tags: json, angularjs, parameters, filter

how can i set a conditional "filter" for the URL parameter's Name and Start date ? i have here a working code. the problem is that if you type a name search field "Name". the start date will also give a value itself. i think because of the "&" delimeter in binding the URL. can anyone has a suggestion about here?

```
    Name:<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="name" />
Start Date:<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="date" />
<button ng-click="search(name,date)" class="blue_button" >search</button>
```

function:

```
    var myTable=angular.module('myTable',[]);
      myTable.controller('tableCtrl',function($scope,$http){
      $http.get("http://staging.api.sample.com/events.json", {headers: {Authorization: 'vuNYhXbpKfH73IjSw856PnGUyOAlmgTW'}})
       .success(function(response) {
          debugger
        $scope.members=response.events;
         $scope.totals = response.paging;
      });

    $scope.search=function(name,date){
         $http.get("http://staging.api.sample.com/events.json?name="+name+"&start_date_from="+date, {headers: {Authorization: 'vuNYhXbpKfH73IjSw856PnGUyOAlmgTW'}})
       .success(function(response) {

        $scope.members=response.events;
         $scope.totals = response.paging;
      });

      }
  });
```

Comment: Can't understand the issue. You need to give more background - you seem to have started from the middle of the issue

Comment: ow sorry. yeah i do have a problem regarding to my table list . if you type a name on a filter "Name" the Url will be undefined . but if you'll going to search for a name again.,it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you use a string builder when you're about to fire the request?

```
$scope.search=function(name,date){
     var requestParams = '?';
     if(name) requestParams += "name= " + name;
     if(name && date) requestParams += "&"
     if(date) requestParams += "start_date_from=" + date;
     // you may want to remove the trailing & if date is not provided

     $http.get("http://staging.api.sample.com/events.json" + requestParams, {headers: {Authorization: 'vuNYhXbpKfH73IjSw856PnGUyOAlmgTW'}})
   .success(function(response) {

    $scope.members=response.events;
     $scope.totals = response.paging;
  });

  }
```

I'd also suggest pulling the data call out in to a angular service.

Comment: .i do have 2 filter 1 for name and 1 for start date my problem here is that if you try to search for a name "Only" let say "John". the program will not work. i check the network , and i found out the URL is  HTTP://STAGING.API.SAMPLE.COM/EVENTS.JSON?NAME=JOHN&START_DATE_FROM=UNDEFINED

Comment: but if am going to search again for name and start date the code will run . Only the first attempt has the problem

Comment: i tried ya code .nothing happens , but that was a great idea . i dunno what is the problem on the first attempt

Comment: finally i configured ya code @jonosma the only problem is that the URL don load . like if i type the name john , the URL be like . "http blah /events.json?name=john&"     maybe because of the "&"

Comment: how's that the URL is good when i look at the NETWORK but it doesn't load the requestParams

Comment: What if we add another conditional in between name and date?                    check out my updated example

Answer (score 0):

Use a service that provides $resource objects.

```
angular.module('myTable')
.factory('Api', function($resource) {
   var BASE_URL = 'http://staging.api.sample.com';

   var events = $resource(BASE_URL + '/events.json', {}, {
     get: {
       method: 'GET',
       cache: true,
       headers: {
         'Authorization': '....'
       }
     }
   });

   return {
     Events: events
   };
});
```

Add the service as a dependency and set optional parameters. Parameters with undefined values will not be set (in case name, date or both are missing)

```
angular.module('myTable')
.controller('tableCtrl',function($scope,$http, Api) {
   $scope.search=function(name,date) {
     Api.Events.get({
       'name': name,
       'date': date
     }).$promise.then(function(successResponse) {
         //Handle success here
     }, function(err) {
         //Handle error here
     });
   };
});
```

Note: `angular.module('myTable',[])` redeclares the `myTable` module. Refer to the Creation versus retrieval section of the [AngularJS module documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module). Relevant bits:

> Beware that using angular.module('myModule', []) will create the
>   module myModule and overwrite any existing module named myModule. Use
>   angular.module('myModule') to retrieve an existing module

Comment: thanks for the code @WeNeigh but ya code is hard to understand for me ,. i tried to replace the function on my post above and put ya code . but nothings happen . 
 
.i do have 2 filter 1 for name and 1 for start date my problem here is that if you try to search for a name "Only" let say "John". the program will not work. i check the network , and i found out the URL is HTTP//STAGING.API.SAMPLE.COM/events.json?name=john&start_date_from= undefined

Comment: but if am going to search again for name and start date the code will run . Only the first attempt has the problem

Comment: Can you change the code to this?

`'name': name || '',
'date': date || ''`